# What is the relation between an affine variety and an affine space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I was learning about algebraic varieties and the wikipedia page presents affine varieties as the "conceptually easiest" type. Having read about affine spaces and affine varieties, I am unsure of how the two concepts are connected.

As I understand it an $n$-dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ over a field $K$ is the same set as the vector space $K^n$ only with some properties "ignored", i.e. there is no privileged origin point and elements may not be added unless the scalar coefficients sum to 0 or 1.

Now as far as I'm aware, an affine variety $V(S)$ for a set of polynomials $S\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is
$$
V(S) = \{ (a_1,\dots,a_n),\; a_i\in K\;\; |\;\; f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0\;\; \forall f \in S \}.
$$
The (admittedly introductory) sources I've read describe the elements of this set as being points in an affine space but seem to effectively treat them as just tuples of $K$-values. Indeed you can associate them to points of an affine space, even points of a vector space if you set $\mathbf{0}=(0,\dots,0)$ but I'm curious as to the motivation for this.

Why is it important that the elements of $V(S)$ be a subset of a set with the structure of an affine space? Is anything lost by ignoring this structure? Conversely, is anything lost if we impose further structure and just say that they're part of a vector space?

Comment: The relationship is that if $\mathbb A$ is an affine space made out of $k^n,$ where $k$ is your field, then the affine subspaces are also affine varieties. So the lines, planes, and hyperplanes in $A$ are varieties - in some sense, the simplest varieties.

Comment: Another key thing is that if you have an affine transformation $k^n\to k^n,$ it corresponds to an automorphism of $\mathbb k[x_1,\dots,k_n].$ (I'm not sure if those are the only automorphisms. I wouldn't be surprised if they were, but a proof isn't coming to me immediately.)

Comment: So, any oval (an affine variety) can be sent to any other oval by some affine transformation. (When you get to projective varieties, you'll see that any conic section can be sent to any conic section, but that isn't true in affine varieties. It is only in projective space where ovals, parabolas and hyperbolas are all finally one kind of thing.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Wouldn't $k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ defined by $x \mapsto x, y \mapsto y - x^2$ be an automorphism of $k[x,y]$ which doesn't come from an affine map?

Comment: Whoops, yep, you are right. @DanielSchepler Deleted my claim

Answer (score 1):

As you've already noted, there is no distinguished origin in an affine space. This means, for example, that you don't have a notion of the sum of two points, or a scalar multiple of a point.

On the other hand, in algebraic geometry, you often want to put a topology on affine space. Here's a quote from *An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry* by Smith, Kahanpaa,
Kekalainen, and Traves (who work over $\mathbb{C}^n$ mostly, rather than a general field):

> To emphasize the difference between the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the
> set $\mathbb{C}^n$ considered as a topological space with its Zariski topology, we will denote the topological space by $\mathbb{A}^n$, and call it *affine n-space*. In particular, there is no distinguished "origin" in $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Why is it important to distinguish between the same set but with different structures? This is partly due to the influence of category theory, and also maybe model theory. Category theory was born partly from the realization that when studying structures, you should study the appropriate maps (morphisms) between them at the same time. For vector spaces, these are the linear maps; these preserve the origin and the vector space operations. For affine varieties, these are the polynomial maps. Very different morphisms for the two different categories.

In model theory, a structure is a domain (or universe) plus relations, constants, and functions on the domain. So here again we need to distinguish.